# How to cite pages with multiple items?

Tags: citing

I know if I cite pages I can

```
\cite[p. 10]{Smith2008}
```

But how do I do this with multiple items? E.g.
(Smith, 2008, p. 10; Jones, 2006, p. 6)

Comment: Depends on your packages. In biblatex there is a "multi cite" command `\cites`.

Comment: Welcome! As indicated already, we don't have enough information to help at the moment. If you could give us a small, minimal document we can compile this will help us understand how you are managing your bibliography and figure out the best answer to your question. As @UlrikeFischer says, if you are using Biblatex, there is `\cites[10]{Smith2008}[6]{Jones2006}`.

Comment: Any chance of a solution with the apacite package?